# Windows Forms unusual mouse manipulation

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I have a Windows Form in which I'm rendering a map that I can zoom in and out of. I have it set so that if you hold the left mouse button, it pans across the map, and if you use the mouse wheel, it zooms in and out on the spot where the mouse cursor currently points. But some of my user base uses Mac hardware, and may not have a mouse with a wheel. I want to be able to hold the right mouse button and move the mouse forward and backward to zoom in and out, but to do this, I need to lock the cursor in place while the right mouse button is clicked. Any thoughts on how to do this?

I've tried Cursor.Position = Point(...) but that doesn't work immediately and causes some bizarre behavior.

Comment: You could cursor.hide() the mouse on right down and replace it by a zoom icon. Then do the zoom stuff in the move and on mouseup or leave bring things back to normal. Take care to not let the icon, maybe a label,  get in the way..

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now, but the problem is that when I lift up the right mouse button, the mouse has moved, even though I'm saving the OnMouseDown point and resetting the Cursor.Position to that value in OnMouseUp.

Comment: I think you need mousecapture. you capture when mousedown and release when mouseup usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why setting the `Cursor.Position` method doesn't work in your case. I have taken a simple windows form without placing any controls I have overided following methods and set the `Cursor.Position` property `OnMouseMove` method. Its working.

Just paste the following code in your form and run it.

```
    Point p = Point.Empty;
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        p = Point.Empty;
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p != Point.Empty)
            Cursor.Position = p;
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
```

Comment: Yea, I realized after I posted this that I wasn't converting the point to screen coordinates, which was my issue. Once I did that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to `Hide` the cursor on `MouseDown`, then `Show` it in `MouseUp`. Till then you can draw the cursor manually if you want to show it.

```
private Point? downPoint;
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    downPoint = this.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    Cursor.Hide();

    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (downPoint.HasValue)
    {
        Cursor.Show();
    }
    downPoint = null;

    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    if (downPoint.HasValue)
    {
        Cursor.Draw(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(downPoint.Value, Cursor.Size));
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus one for `Cursor.Draw`

Comment: I repeat the comment I made in the comment chain above. I'm basically doing that already, but when I lift the mouse button, the cursor has moved, even though I'm setting the Cursor.Position field in OnMouseUp

Comment: No it doesn't. You need to save the point as  `downPoint= Cursor.Position;` not as `downPoint= e.Location;` for the restore, so the simplest way is to save __two__ points, one for restoring, the other one for drawing the fake cursor!

Comment: KairisCharm, @Taw 's comment should have helped you; if not post the code which you claim is not working. Post short but complete code, which mean it should be compilable and reproducing the problem. So that it will be easy for us to help.